# Удаление вектора из двумерного массива векторов

Tags: c++, vector

Есть два двумерных вектора которые перебираются через foreach и если значения совпали, то вектор в векторе удаляется (удаляю целый вектор т.к. он сам состоит из TCHAR), но выдаётся ошибка:

```
 "отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase [с _Tp=std::vector<TCHAR, std::allocator<wchar_t>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::vector<TCHAR, std::allocator<wchar_t>>>]", соответствующие списку аргументов"

        //copy arrays for don't damage data (I think it's safer)

        vector<vector<TCHAR>> proccessNow = activeProccessesNow;
        vector<vector<TCHAR>> proccessPreviously = activeProccessesPreviously;


        for (auto Now : activeProccessesNow)
        {
            int i = 0;
            for (auto Previously : activeProccessesPreviously)
            {
                int j = 0;

                if (Previously == Now)
                {
                    proccessNow.erase(i);
                    proccessPreviously.erase(j);
                }
                else{}
            }

        }
```

Comment: Вы всегда удаляете первые элементы вектора? Ну, у вас и `i`, и `j` в цикле не меняются и равно 0.

Comment: в последствии i и j меняются, когда код подрезал для того, чтобы понятнее было не заметил, что убрал `j++;` и `i++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

плюсам не нравится когда в erase передают просто переменную, поэтому код пришлось усложнить, просто добавив `vector.begin()`  и добавляем нашу переменную

```
proccessNow.erase(next(proccessNow.begin(),i));
proccessPreviously.erase(next(proccessPreviously.begin(),j));
```

UPD: Спасибо @Mikhailo за исправление неточного ответа и улучшение кода)

Comment: Вы неправы. 'begin()' возвращает **не значение, а итератор**. В вопросе вы пытаетесь передать функции `erase` число, а передавать надо итератор. И простое сложение работает не со всеми итераторами, а только для контейнеров с произвольным доступом. Правильнее `proccessNow.erase(next(proccessNow.begin(),i));`

Comment: спасибо за объяснение и исправление кода)